# My Event Tracking inst working?

Tags: google-analytics, jquery, google-ads-api

My event tracking isnt working on my Google analytic's. Below is the code that it gave me to insert into the webpage and below that is the snippet it told me to put. I am wanting to track the number of clicks onto a 'mailto' link from the website and I believe this is the best way to do it?

Can anyone tell me where its going wrong?

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-37080107-2', 'promat-durasteel.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This is the snippet: (it wont let me put the opening tag on this forum for some reason, but it is there in the coding!

href="mailto:info@sharpfibre.com" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview, '/Direct-Email-Enquiry-Link-Clicked’]);">info@sharpfibre.com

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you are mixing two brands of Google Analytics  - the new "Universal Analytics" and the , ehm, traditional asynchronous tracking code. Pushing values to the _gaq-Array will not help you since Universal Analytics does not use _gaq (and even if it would you are tracking a (virtual) pageview, not an event).

You'll have to use ga('send') on the click event. Documentation for event tracking with the new GA code is here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: ok thanks, so what would the snippet code be for the mailto: link be? Im new to this universal analytics so Im not sure exactly sure how to code it!